# _tkinter.TclError: encountered an unsupported criticial chunk type "exIf"

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

So I am trying to put some pictures into my window and whenever I run the program it gives me this error:

> _tkinter.TclError: encountered an unsupported criticial chunk type "exIf"

I tried putting it into other formats, such as *.jpg*, *.png* and *.gif*, but they don't work. Can you please help me?

This is my code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

class Window:
def __init__(self, master):
    self.master = master
    master.iconbitmap('ta.ico')
    master.title('Tamagochi')
    master.minsize(width=480, height=240)
    master.maxsize(width=480, height=240)

    self.pic1 = PhotoImage(file='pic1.png')
    self.pic2 = PhotoImage(file='pic2.png')
    self.pic3 = PhotoImage(file='pic3.png')
    self.pic4 = PhotoImage(file='pic4.png')

    self.smFrame = ttk.Frame(master)
    self.smButton1 = ttk.Button(self.smFrame, text='Start', command=self.start)
    self.smButton2 = ttk.Button(self.smFrame, text='Options', command=self.options)
    self.smButton3 = ttk.Button(self.smFrame, text='Quit', command=self.quit)
    self.smPhoto1 = ttk.Label(self.smFrame, image=self.pic1)

    self.smFrame.pack()
    self.smPhoto1.grid()
    self.smButton1.grid(pady=40, padx=200)
    self.smButton2.grid(pady=0, padx=200)
    self.smButton3.grid(pady=40, padx=200)
def start(self):
    pass
def options(self):
    pass
def quit(self):
    exit()
root = Tk()
Window(root)
root.mainloop()
```

This is the full error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/NemPl/Desktop/ProLan/Python/Python programi/Tamagochi/Tamagochi.py", line 35, in <module>
    Window(root)
  File "C:/Users/NemPl/Desktop/ProLan/Python/Python programi/Tamagochi/Tamagochi.py", line 14, in __init__
    self.pic3 = PhotoImage(file='pic3.png')
  File "C:\Users\NemPl\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 3539, in __init__
    Image.__init__(self, 'photo', name, cnf, master, **kw)
  File "C:\Users\NemPl\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 3495, in __init__
    self.tk.call(('image', 'create', imgtype, name,) + options)
_tkinter.TclError: encountered an unsupported criticial chunk type "exIf"
```

Comment: Could you please show us exactly the traceback? We need to understand for sure at which line the error is being thrown.

Comment: and please post a complete, minimal, verifiable example of executable code. your sample lacks all the import information.

Comment: I have updated it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`PhotoImage`](http://mgltools.scripps.edu/api/DejaVu/Tkinter.PhotoImage-class.html) is a `tkinter` class which, unfortunately, can not deal with *.png* files.

The solution is to rely on the [*Python Imaging Library*](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/)<sup>1</sup> which offers support to several image formats and transforms them to image objects that can be "*understood*" by `tkinter`:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

self.img1 = Image.open("pic1.png")
self.pic1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.img1)
```

---

<sub><sup>1. You can install PIL as described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/156484/how-do-i-install-python-imaging-library-pil/596516).</sup></sub>

Comment: Hmm, I was watching a tutorial and they were able to use .png. I guess they changed it.

Comment: Tcl/Tk 8.6 includes png support in the Tk core.

Answer (score 1):

Just wanted to share a solution that solved for me!

I figured out that other '.png' images were working with the same code, so the problem was happening with the image file.

What solved my problem was simply modifying the image (just saved it from a image editor).